# Generate path array from parent_id-array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array from database with id-parent_id values:

```
[0] => Array
    (
    [id] => 45
    [parent_id] => 
    [name] => 1
    )        
[2] => Array
    (
    [id] => 152
    [parent_id] => 45
    [name] => 2
    )

[3] => Array
    (
    [id] => 153
    [parent_id] => 152
    [name] => 3
    )
```

And I need to get array with a path

```
[0] => 1      
[2] => 1/2
[3] => 1/2/3
```

I cant wrote function to do this.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Your expected output makes no sense to me. (Having just the information you gave)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getArrayRecursive ($array, $pid) {
    $id = NULL;
    array_walk($array, function ($subarray, $key) use (&$id, $pid) { if ($subarray["id"] == $pid) $id = $key; });
    return is_null($id)?"":getArrayRecursive($array, $array[$id]["parent_id"]).$array[$id]["name"]."/";
}

$newArray = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $subarray) {
    $newArray[$key] = getArrayRecursive($array, $subarray["parent_id"]).$subarray["name"];
}
```

P.s.: you can also do this iteratively. With a while loop in the foreach loop.

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => asdas/asdas
    [2] => asdas
    [3] => asdas/asdas/asdas
    [4] => 4/3/2/1
    [5] => asdas/asdas
    [6] => 2/1
    [7] => 3/2/1
    [8] => asdas/asdas
    [9] => asdas
)

Comment: @user2307848 Just changed order. Now better?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($arrays as $array){
    $newArray[] = empty($array['parent_id']) ? $array['name'] : $newArray[$i-1] . '/'. getParent($arrays, $array['parent_id']);
    $i++;
}

print'<pre>';print_r($newArray);print'</pre>';

function getParent($arr, $parent){
    foreach($arr as $k =>  $v){
        if(isset($v['parent_id']) && $v['parent_id'] == $parent) return $v['name'];
    }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit?

Comment: Not workin with next keys
I got this:
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1/asdas
    [2] => 1/asdas/asdas
    [3] => 1/asdas/asdas/asdas
    [4] => 1/asdas/asdas/asdas/4
    [5] => 1/asdas/asdas/asdas/4/asdas
    [6] => 1/asdas/asdas/asdas/4/asdas/2
    [7] => 1/asdas/asdas/asdas/4/asdas/2/3
    [8] => 1/asdas/asdas/asdas/4/asdas/2/3/asdas
    [9] => 1/asdas/asdas/asdas/4/asdas/2/3/asdas/asdas
)

Comment: The array in question contains a key of [name] which seems to allways contain an integer. (incrementing) The desired output seems to be a series of values from this name key.