# PHP Array: Generate a id_path and level from id and parenth id

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

From this table:
[From this table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WagCX.png)

I get this array in PHP:
[array in PHP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRcNq.png)

To this array I want to add a new line, I know category_id and parent_id, how do I program the id_path and the level ?

Edited1:
As example the last line: category_id:107 , parent_id:106, how to code id_path=96/106/107 and level?
id_path: A sequence of category IDs separated by slashes

Edited2:

```php
    function test() {
        $arGiven = [ 
            [
                'category_id' => 100,
                'parent_id' => 107,
                'id_path' => '',
                'level' => 0,
            ],
            [
                'category_id' => 106,
                'parent_id' => 96,
                'id_path' => '',
                'level' => 0,
            ],
            [
                'category_id' => 107,
                'parent_id' => 106,
                'id_path' => '',
                'level' => 0,
            ]

        ];

        $arExpected = [ 
            [
                'category_id' => 100,
                'parent_id' => 107,
                'id_path' => '96/106/107/100',
                'level' => 4,
            ],
            [
                'category_id' => 106,
                'parent_id' => 96,
                'id_path' => '96/106',
                'level' => 2,
            ],
            [
                'category_id' => 107,
                'parent_id' => 106,
                'id_path' => '96/106/107',
                'level' => 3,
            ]

        ];

        $result = $arGiven;

        return $result;
    }
```

Edited3:
I tried it with this code:

```php
    function test() {
        $arGiven = [ 
            [
                'category_id' => 100,
                'parent_id' => 107,
                'id_path' => '',
                'level' => 0,
            ],
            [
                'category_id' => 106,
                'parent_id' => 96,
                'id_path' => '',
                'level' => 0,
            ],
            [
                'category_id' => 107,
                'parent_id' => 106,
                'id_path' => '',
                'level' => 0,
            ]

        ];

        $arExpected = [ 
            [
                'category_id' => 100,
                'parent_id' => 107,
                'id_path' => '96/106/107/100',
                'level' => 4,
            ],
            [
                'category_id' => 106,
                'parent_id' => 96,
                'id_path' => '96/106',
                'level' => 2,
            ],
            [
                'category_id' => 107,
                'parent_id' => 106,
                'id_path' => '96/106/107',
                'level' => 3,
            ]

        ];

        $arrays = $arGiven;

        function getParent($arr, $parent){
            foreach($arr as $v){
                if($v['parent_id'] == $parent) return $v['parent_id'];
            }
        
          return false;
        }

        $newArray=[];
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($arrays as $array){
            $newArray[] = $newArray[$i-1] . '/'. getParent($arrays, $array['parent_id']);
            $i++;
        }

        $test=1;
        return $array;
    }
```

But $newArray is

```
[ 
  "/107",
  "/107/96",
  "/107/96/106"
]
```

Instead of:

```
[
    '96/106/107/100',
    '96/106',
    '96/106/107'
]
```

Comment: I don't quite understand your question, do you want to append a line at the end of the array with variables you already have? What have you done so far? What error do you get?

Comment: How do i generate with foreach or array.map the id_path and the level? See pictures for a new line. I need a new function.

Comment: I have found this for generating the id_path in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150199/generate-path-array-from-parent-id-array, but I can't find a solution to change the examples to my array so that the id path is like on the pictures.

Comment: Okay, and what have you tried so far? Which errors do you get? Show us some code, else we can't help you debugging anything.

Comment: I have expanded the question with an actual and a target. I try to rewrite the examples from the other thread again, when I tried it, it didn't work, and then write the result.

Comment: @GreenPepper I have extended the question with fail code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure it can be really optimized :

```
<?php
    $arGiven = [ 
    // add the root category
        [
            'category_id' => 96,
            'parent_id' => 0,
            'id_path' => '',
            'level' => 0,
        ],
        [
            'category_id' => 100,
            'parent_id' => 107,
            'id_path' => '',
            'level' => 0,
        ],
        [
            'category_id' => 106,
            'parent_id' => 96,
            'id_path' => '',
            'level' => 0,
        ],
        [
            'category_id' => 107,
            'parent_id' => 106,
            'id_path' => '',
            'level' => 0,
        ]
    ];

    $level = 0;
    $parentLevelIds = [0];
    do {
        $level++;
        
        $nextParentLevelIds = [];
        $arGiven = array_map(function($value) use($level, $parentLevelIds, &$nextParentLevelIds, $arGiven) {
            if (in_array($value['parent_id'], $parentLevelIds)) {
                $path = '';
                if ($value['parent_id'] !== 0) {
                    $parent = array_filter($arGiven, function($parentSearchValue) use ($value) {
                        return $parentSearchValue['category_id'] == $value['parent_id'];
                    });
                    if (!empty($parent)) {
                        $path = array_shift($parent)['id_path'];
                    }
                }
                $value['level'] = $level;
                $value['id_path'] = empty($path) ? $value['category_id'] : ( $path . '/' . $value['category_id'] );
                $nextParentLevelIds[] = $value['category_id'];
            }
            return $value;
        }, $arGiven);

        $parentLevelIds = $nextParentLevelIds;

        $hasLevel0 = !empty(array_filter($arGiven, function($value) {
            return $value['level'] == 0;
        }));
    } while ($hasLevel0);
```